# Need help with an equation

Tags: equations, formatting

I have little trouble with my TeX course. I've already completed all the assignments except one. Yesterday I was up until 4AM and still didn't get it right.

Maybe someone could give me some guidelines or even the code? I would *really* appreciate it!

Here is what I have so far and what would be ideal:

[image]

I used tables to create this, but I'm getting the feeling that it's a wrong approach.

---

PS.

What would be correct to use for doing these (I don't know what they're called in English).

[image]

I've used `\left`, `\right` and `\start{array}` so far, but it somehow doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to try my hand at this with Plain-format, because the example seemed (to me) to lack consistency. That is, only the very last entry above the `\hrule` got an alignment. So here's what it'd look like if the rest of them are aligned:

```
\def\myeqalign#1{\openup-1\jot\eqalign{#1}}% negate the cumulative \openup1\jot
\let\To\Rightarrow
$$\myeqalign{% creates a 2-col align (1st col flush-right, 2nd flush-left),
             % which starts off with \openup1\jot
  \omit% omit the align preamble for this col, 'cause we don't want flush-right
    $\left\{\myeqalign{y&=2x-5\cr4x-2y-10&=0\cr}\right.\To$\hfill\cr
  \noalign{\smallskip}% insert a small vertical skip between the rows
  \To\left\{\myeqalign{2x-y-5=0\cr4x-2y-10=0}\right.
    \left|\matrix{\cdot(-2)\cr\cdot1}\right|
    +\myeqalign{-4x+2y+10&=0\cr4x-2y-10&=0\cr}\cr\noalign{\hrule}
  0=0\,}$$
```

[image]

Whereas, if I am trying to mimic the "*This is what I need"-part*:

```
$$\myeqalign{\omit$\cases{y=2x-5\cr4x-2y-10=0}\;\To$\hfil\cr\noalign{\medskip}
  \To\cases{2x-y-5=0\cr4x-2y-10=0}\enspace\left|\matrix{\cdot(-2)\cr\cdot1}\right|\enspace
    +\myeqalign{-4x+2y+10&=0\cr4x-2y-10&=0}\cr\noalign{\hrule}
  0=0}$$
\bye
```

[image]

There are additional differences with both horizontal and vertical spacing.

To wrap it up, Plain's `\matrix` centers its column contents, with columns `\quad` apart from eachother. `\eqalign` has two columns; first flush-right, second flush-left. `\cases` has two columns; first flush-left in math-mode, and the second in text-mode, `\quad` apart.

Regardless of which one you'll use (and I'm pretty sure this includes LaTeX's equivalents), you'll always end up using `\halign` (horizontal alignment) "under the hood", which can be thought of as a table.

Answer (score 6):

- You could use a `cases` environment
- You can use `aligned`, such as

  ```
  \left\{\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}\right.
  ```
- An `array` environment for the whole structure would be ok. In contrast to `tabular`, `array` works in math mode.

Answer (score 5):

I used an `array` with three centered columns and vertical lines separating columns one and two, and two and three and other nested `array` environments; `\multicolumn` was used to suppress the vertical lines in the first and in the third rows, and to get the alignment for the last row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{@{}c|c|c}
  \multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{%
    \left\lbrace\begin{array}{l}
      y = 2x - 5 \\
      4x - 2y - 10 = 0
    \end{array}\right.\Rightarrow} 
  &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \\
  \Rightarrow\left\lbrace\begin{array}{l}
    2x - y + 5 = 0 \\
    4x - 2y - 10 = 0
  \end{array}\right.
  & \begin{array}{c}
    \cdot (-2) \\ \cdot (1) 
  \end{array}
  & +\begin{array}{r}
    -4x +2y -10 = 0 \\
    4x -2y -10 = 0
  \end{array} \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{r}{0 = 0}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: corrected the last pair of equations.
EDIT2: suppressed a superfluous column.

Comment: Why is the outer array made of four columns? And why the empty `\multicolumn`'s? Less is more. :)

Comment: @egreg: I was just about to eliminate the superfluous column. The empty `\multicolumn` is to prevent the vertical line in the first row between columns two and three.

Answer (score 3):

The whole thing is a one column array with left alignment; there are two rows and a `\hline` to separate the result which is

```
\multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{0=0}
```

For the system you can do

```
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{l}
first equation\\
second equation
\end{array}\right.
```

The second row of the main array is made of an arrow, a system, another array with different delimiters, the `+` symbol, and a final array with no delimiters.

```
\[
\begin{array}{l}
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{l}
  y = 2x - 5 \\
  4x - 2y - 10 = 0
\end{array}\right.\Rightarrow
\\[\bigskipamount]
\Rightarrow
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{l}
  2x - y + 5 = 0 \\
  4x - 2y - 10 = 0
\end{array}\right.
\ \left|\begin{array}{c}
  \cdot (-2) \\ \cdot (1)
\end{array}\right|
+
\begin{array}{r}
  -4x +2y -10 = 0 \\
  4x -2y -10 = 0
\end{array} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{r}{0 = 0}
\end{array}
\]
```